# Linphone SDK not build android

Tags: android, sip, linphone

Linphone SDK demo not build in the android studio. It always gives the same error that is "Cause: path may not be null or empty string. path=''".
I am also clear the gradle.properties file but it still gives the same error.
Please guide me to run this demo.

Answer (score 1):

i ve fixed that in build gradle file (or maybe they fixed in last release)

```
eachFile {
  if(path!=null && path !="") {
    path = path.toLowerCase() //to workaround case insensitive fs (macosx)
    println("Syncing sdk asset ${sourcePath} to ${path}")
  }
}
```

An other point, build for just the arch you need , for example (for emulator)

```
 ./prepare -c
 ./prepare x86  or ./prepare x86_64
```